# Blue Origin's BE-3PM Engine: 18-100% Throttle Range, How?

Tags: blue-origin, new-shepard, be-3, be-4, throttle

Blue Origin says the BE-3PM engine in its New Shepard vehicle can throttle down to 18% max thrust.

Compare to 57% for the Merlin 1D engine in stage 1 of SpaceX's Falcon 9 (and to 39% for the Merlin Vacuum engine in stage 2, though stage 2 doesn't have to land, and its on landing approach that low throttle would most help).

**So I'm wondering:** What are the challenges in increasing throttle range, and what keeps SpaceX from matching Blue Origin's 18%?

The BE-3 runs on liquid hydrogen while the Merlin runs on RP-1. Does the choice of fuel account for the difference? And could it be the big reason why Blue Origin chose that difficult fuel for New Shepard?

---

There is some background information available in answer(s) to [Do Blue Origin's BE-3 engines need to run for 7 seconds to "warm up"?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/26994/12102)

Comment: SSME: LH2, min throttle 65% (later upped to 67%).

Comment: Oh wow. That really puts Blue Origin's 18% in perspective. And I guess the choice of hydrogen by itself wouldn't magically increase your throttle range.

Comment: Another example, the RS-68 is a gas-generator cycle (like the Merlin) burning liquid hydrogen fuel, with a minimum throttle of 58%.

Comment: Could it be the physical scale(size) of the engine? I'm thinking of Reynolds number type effects in the exhaust flow but I am no expert on that.

Comment: Interesting! New Glenn is about double the diameter of Falcon 9, and stage 2 of New Glenn fits two BE-3 engines, while stage 2 of Falcon 9 fits one Merlin Vac engine. So each BE-3 engine should be about the same diameter as a Merlin Vac, maybe a bit smaller. The (gigantic) Merlin Vac does have a deeper throttle range, down to 39% throttle, vs. 57% of the standard Merlins on stage 1. Maybe size explains the throttle range difference in the Merlins too? I"m very curious what the throttle range would be on the BE-4s in stage 1 of New Glenn---although, BE-3 uses LH while BE-4 uses methane, so...

Comment: [Apparently the engine can throttled using a combination of all three valves.](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41896/12102)

Comment: Some info here about coupling between injector pressure and chamber pressure and how it falls apart and low throttle values: https://yarchive.net/space/rocket/deep_throttling.html

Comment: Also based on the relation of $P_c = \dot{m} c^{*} / A_t$, reducing the mass flow rate to throttle the engine will decrease chamber pressure, and consequently nozzle exit pressure. When exit pressure falls below ~1/3 of ambient pressure, flow separation due to severe overexpansion in the nozzle becomes a concern, which can be a limiting design constraint.

Comment: How does this compare to the Apollo descent engine?

Comment: Related: [Is there a way to make liquid fueled rockets not lose efficiency with decreasing throttle?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28083/195)

Comment: @ikrase LM descent engine was designed to throttle down to 10%, and this was used for course corrections during Apollo 13, though nominal flight profiles didn't need to go below 25%.